# Basis of nonzero subgroup of free abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, abelian-groups

Theorem 38.11 in *First Course in Abstract Algebra*, Fraleigh.

> Let $G$ be a nonzero free abelian group of finite rank $n$, and let $K$ be a nonzero subgroup of $G$.
>   Then $K$ is a free abelian group of rank $s\le n$. Furthermore, there exists a basis $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \}$ for $G$ and positive integers, $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_s$ where $d_i$ divides $d_{i+1}$ for $i=1, 2, \dots, s-1$, such that $\{d_1x_1, d_2x_2, \dots, d_sx_s \}$ is a basis for $K$.

[image: proof of Theorem 37.11]

[image]

In this proof, I don't understand existence of $Y_1$. While we cannot gaurantee that we have finite number of bases for $G$, how can we define $Y_1$ having some nonzero element of $K$ with the least such nonzero value $|k_i|$?

Comment: There is a map from the collection of bases to the positive integers, sending each base $Y$ to the smallest positive integer that occurs. This is a nonempty subset of positive integers, so it has a smallest element. That smallest element comes form some basis, so take that basis.

Comment: I didn't consider Well-order of natural number. Thanks for your kindness.